# Add files to global ignore list cornerstone svn

Tags: svn, cornerstone

I use Dreamweaver to edit my sites, because it creates the "_notes" folders I would like to know how to add "_notes" to a global ignore list. Currently I have only figured out how to do this for each repository. I would like to have it know to ignore this even when I create a new repository.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will post in hopes this will help someone else.

The global ignore list is located in the **preferences > subversion**. 
Just uncheck use default global ignores and add your own.